# Delimiters and multiple parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use the mod_rewrite module to create smooth URLs. So for example my `example.com/pages/group/index.php?id=1&slug=example-keyword` would become `example.com/group/1-example-keyword`.

The problem I'm having is with the second parameter and how it is split. As the second parameter uses dashes how could I fix this as at the moment it throws 404 errors.

**.htaccess rule**

```
RewriteRule ^group/([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ /pages/group/index.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression explicitly prohibits dashes in the first and second groups.

Try this using `.` (any character) instead of `[^-]` (any character except `-`) in your second group:

```
RewriteRule ^group/([^-]*)-(.*)$ /pages/group/index.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L]
```

In this expression, everything after `group/` but before the first `-` will be captured in group 1, and everything after the first `-` will be captured in group 2.